# installation of Dot net framework when later framework is exists

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have dot net framework 4.0 and 4.5 already installed on the machine. But Dot net framework 3.5 is not installed.

I tried installing 3.5 but getting error indicating that later version is already installed.

Please guide me for the same.

Comment: I think you have to enable 3.5 via "Programs and Features" -> "Add/Remove Windows Features"

Comment: One of those versions, I forget which one, supersedes 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y549e41e(v=vs.100).aspx) has this to say:

> You can install and run multiple versions of the .NET Framework on a
>   computer. You can install the versions in any order. To see which
>   versions are installed, view the %WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework
>   directory. (You should also view the Framework64 directory on a 64-bit
>   computer, which can have 32 or 64-bit versions installed.) Each
>   version of the .NET Framework has a directory, and the first two
>   digits of the directory name identify the .NET Framework version; for
>   example: v1.1.4322 for the .NET Framework 1.1, v2.0.50727 for the .NET
>   Framework 2.0, v3.5 for the .NET Framework 3.5, and so on.

So, it should be possible to install any major version. I suspect that you already have 3.5 on your machine, installed automatically by the OS or some software, which is why you get the message.

I recommend looking in the framework folders as described above to see which versions you actually have.